# how to insert null date on detailsview

Tags: c#, date, null

I've set up in the database and dataset that the date column may contain a null value. however, when the program runs it always requests that the date column be filled in. the error is as follows:

> Additional information: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

```
<div>        
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="IDREFUNDSELESAI" DataSourceID="RefundSelesaiObjectDataSource">
        <Fields>                               
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TANGGAL" HeaderText="TANGGAL" SortExpression="TANGGAL" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
```

---

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="RefundSelesaiObjectDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetRefundSelesaiByIdRefund" TypeName="dms_mkph.bll.RefundSelesaiClass" DeleteMethod="DeleteRefundSelesai" InsertMethod="AddRefundSelesai" UpdateMethod="UpdateRefundSelesai"  >           
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="idRefundSelesai" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="TANGGAL" Type="DateTime" />
```

bll.cs

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Insert, true)]
    public bool AddRefundSelesai(DateTime TANGGAL)
    {
        // Create a new ProductRow instance
        RefundDataSet.REFUNDSELESAIDataTable dtRefundSelesai = new RefundDataSet.REFUNDSELESAIDataTable();
        RefundDataSet.REFUNDSELESAIRow rRefundSelesai = dtRefundSelesai.NewREFUNDSELESAIRow();                

        if (TANGGAL == null) rRefundSelesai.SetTANGGALNull(); else rRefundSelesai.TANGGAL = TANGGAL;
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime` is a value type. Value types can't be null. Well unless you use the Nullable type

Try

```
<asp:Parameter Name="TANGGAL" Type="DateTime?" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
```

and

```
public bool AddRefundSelesai(DateTime? TANGGAL)
```

Comment: thank you, you 're right. I need change AddRefundSelesai(DateTime to DateTime?